# Windows Command TYPE Keywords in Quotes

Tags: json, windows, cmd, command-line

I'm trying to pass the TYPE keyword in the Windows command line to read a file and output its contents in a parameter.

I want to read the contents of 'state-machine.json' into my string... with bash I know I can use:

```
aws stepfunctions --endpoint http://localhost:8083 create-state-machine --definition "$(cat ./step-function/state-machine.json)"
```

However I can't figure out the Windows equivalent:

```
aws stepfunctions --endpoint http://localhost:8083 create-state-machine --definition  "@(type ./step-function/state-machine.json)"
```

Comment: it might help if you put the contents of state-machine.json in your question.

Comment: Is `"@(type ./step-function/state-machine.json)"` supposed to be a powershell command?

Comment: @somebadhat It is simply a JSON string that I want to extract from the file.  TYPE is  a command: https://ss64.com/nt/type.html

Comment: are you trying to do this with powershell?  Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Is "@(type ./step-function/state-machine.json)" supposed to be a powershell command?

```
$StateMachine=gc "path-to\state-machine.json"

aws stepfunctions --endpoint http://localhost:8083 create-state-machine --definition  "@("$StateMachine")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following solved my issue:

`create-state-machine --definition file://step-function/state-machine.json`